# matPutVariable: error (matrix::serialize::WrongSize) trying to output data to mat file

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex, mat-file

I have a created a simulator in C/C++ that is supposed to output the results in a .mat file that can be imported into some visualization tools in Matlab.

During the simulation results are stored in a data buffer. The buffer is a `std::map<const char *, double *>`, where the string should be the same name as the corresponding matlab struct field, and the double* is the buffered data.

At the end of the simulation I then use the following code to write the buffered data into a .mat file

```
const char **fieldnames; // Declared and populated in another class method
int numFields; // Declared in another method. Equal to fieldnames length.
int buffer_size; // Declared in another method. Equal to number of timesteps in simulation.

std::map<const char *, double *> field_data;
std::map<const char *, mxArray *> field_matrices;

// Open .mat file
MATFile *pmat = matOpen(filename.str().c_str(), "w");

// Create an empty Matlab struct of the right size
mxArray *SimData_struct = mxCreateStructMatrix(1,1,this->numFields,this->fieldnames);

int rows=this->buffer_size, cols=1;

for(int i=0; i<this->numFields; i++) {

   // Create an empty matlab array for each struct field
   field_matrices[this->fieldnames[i]] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(rows, cols, mxREAL);

   // Copy data from buffers to struct fields
   memcpy(mxGetPr(field_matrices[this->fieldnames[i]]), this->field_data[this->fieldnames[i]], rows * cols * sizeof(double));

   // Insert arrays into the struct
   mxSetField(SimData_struct,0,this->fieldnames[i],field_matrices[this->fieldnames[i]]);

}

matPutVariable(pmat, object_name.str().c_str(), SimData_struct);
```

I can compile and start the simulation, but it dies with an error when the matPutVariable command is reached. The error I get is `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'matrix::serialize::WrongSize'`. I have tried to google for more information, but have been unable to find something that could help me.

---

Mathworks support helped me to identify the cause of the issue. My application uses boost 1.55, but Matlab uses 1.49. There was a clash between those dependencies that was solved by adding an additional external dependencies directory path.

```
-Wl,-rpath={matlab path}/bin/glnxa64
```

Comment: just to be clear, this is a standalone program not a MEX-function right?

Comment: Correct. I use the mx and mat c++ libraries in a Unix application.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the error with a simple example, but I don't see the problem. Here is my code:

#### test_mat_api.cpp

```cpp
#include "mat.h"
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // output MAT-file
    MATFile *pmat = matOpen("out.mat", "w");

    // create a scalar struct array with two fields
    const char *fieldnames[2] = {"a", "b"};
    mxArray *s = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, 2, fieldnames);

    // fill struct fields
    for (mwIndex i=0; i<2; i++) {
        // 10x1 vector
        mxArray *arr = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(10, 1, mxREAL);
        double *x = mxGetPr(arr);
        std::fill(x, x+10, i);

        // assign field
        mxSetField(s, 0, fieldnames[i], arr);
    }

    // write struct to MAT-file
    matPutVariable(pmat, "my_struct", s);

    // cleanup
    mxDestroyArray(s);
    matClose(pmat);

    return 0;
}
```

First I compile the standalone program:

```matlab
>> mex -client engine -largeArrayDims test_map_api.cpp
```

Next I run the executable:

```matlab
>> !test_map_api.exe
```

Finally I load the created MAT-file in MATLAB:

```matlab
>> whos -file out.mat
  Name           Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  my_struct      1x1               512  struct              

>> load out.mat

>> my_struct
my_struct = 
    a: [10x1 double]
    b: [10x1 double]

>> (my_struct.b)'
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

So everything runs successfully (I'm using MATLAB R2014a on Windows x64).

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. It was originally a colleague of mine who wrote the code. He wrote a simple script just to try it out, and I incorporated it into the actual application. For him it worked, but not for me. Very strange. I will continue to work on it and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Just to clarify, I get the same error when I run your code. Have not tried it in a new (empty) project though. Might be an idea.

Comment: @FabianJonsson: The code above works fine for me, so maybe you have a problem elsewhere in your code... Is your application multi-threaded? I ask because the MAT and MX APIs are not thread-safe.